# Encrypting a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm with a doubt about SQLite in Android. In the [SQLite documentation](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html), they say that I can encrypt my database using the following command before anything:

```
PRAGMA key=text-key;
PRAGMA hexkey=hexadecimal-key;
```

But when I use this in Android the database isn't encrypted:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA key=<mykey>");    
db.execSQL("PRAGMA key=<myhexakey>");
```

For now, I'm using SQLCipher to encrypt my database, but I don't want to use this because of the dependencies (allright, I know that is not too large).

I try to search and don't find anything about it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's SQLite Encryption Extension. Not something shipped with core sqlite nor found in Android.

Comment: @laalto, thanks a lot, so, there isn't a way to encrypt database through native API?

Comment: No, use a third party library like SQLCipher.

Comment: @laalto, thanks again, allright, I will continue using SQLCipher

Comment: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/